# Finding the exact path of the file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the fileUpload control. When I upload the file, I want to find the exact location of the file.

I tried using:

1. `string fname=  Server.MapPath(FileUpload2.FileName);`
2. `string fname=  FileUpload2.FileName;`
3. `string fname=  FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;`

Numbers 2 & 3 gave me the name of the file. Number 1 gave me the the path of my website location. I do not know what is the difference between 2 and 3, why both gave me same results.

I read somewhere, that you cannot get the path. Is it true? If not, what code should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual file path because a file uploaded to the server is simply held in memory.

The [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control is just a wrapper around an [`HttpPostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) instance, which itself is basically just a wrapper around an `InputStream`.

**It's up to you to actually *save* the file somewhere.** Until then it doesn't exist in any physical location.

The [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx) property simply corresponds to the filename from the client's machine, minus the path. It has no correlation to anything on the server's file system.

There are a couple of different ways you can deal with the file.

### Save The File To Disk:

The FileUpload control provides a [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) method that will allow you to save the file locally, or some UNC that you have access to.

```
FileUpload2.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\" + FileUpload2.FileName);
```

### Process The File In Memory:

Since you have access to the [`FileContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx), you could simply manipulate and process the file directly. Assuming you know what type of file it is (txt, pdf, csv, etc...)

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(FileUpload2.FileContent)) 
{
    while ((var line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        //Do something with 'line'
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose I want to read the file,, so I pass the variable fname to File.ReadAllLines(fname), here it wont read the file, so in that case what should I do.. reading a file for example.